# Windows Universal App Suspend State and Events

Tags: events, event-handling, win-universal-app

I have an UWP that starts a background task that got fired every 15 Minutes.
On the MainPage of the UI the Complete Event for that task is set and called.

I played a bit to see how events where handled if the application goes to the background or even got suspended.

I came to the expression that all events got queued and are processed when the application leaves the suspended state.

This is not what I had in mind. I need an option to only process an event once and ignore all other events raised during the suspend of the UI.
The work I have to process during the OnComplete event is quite time consuming so it is very ineffective to call that multiple times and the result would not change either.

One option would be to set the last run time of the event and ignore calls inside a given timespan, but is there no default way to handle these inside the event system?

I took the MS example for background tasks um UWP. In this example application you can register a task and when the task got called it counts from 0 to 100 in steps of then and displays the percentage on the main windows. It is quite an easy example an can be downloaded from github (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples).
The example uses the OnProcess event but it makes no difference.
What I done
1) Start the Application
2) Register Background Task
3) Run the Task though Visual Studio Process Location Toolbar
4) While the task is running set the Application to Suspended via the Process Location Toolbar
5) Wait a bit and that Resume the Application
6) With a breakpoint in the OnProcess Method of the example I could see now that this method is know called several times (Once for each Raise Event Call in the Background Task.

What I want is that if the Application Resumes the EventMethod will only processed once for all RaiseEvents that are waiting to be processed

Comment: Did you mean you don't want the `OnCompleted` event triggered for current completed background task once the app get suspending? Even the app resumed, the `OnCompleted` should not be triggered for that task? Only for current task or once app suspended and then resumed, the later tasks will all not trigger the event? By the way what "how tat" here, did mean "task"? If I misunderstand you please detail more.

Comment: I added some explanations to made it more clear what I want.
For short I want that all waiting "OnCompleted" calles that are currently in the waiting queue are handled with one Call of the Method